# Duda sobre constructores en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy recién comenzando a programar y cuando llegue a un ejercicio de POO en PHP me surgieron dudas con los constructores. Como verán en la imagen de abajo, se pide un constructor que inicialize una fecha fija que yo defina y otro que reciba como parámetros para inicializar la fecha y a pesar de ver varios tutoriales de youtube estoy algo perdido en cuanto como seria un constructor con un valor fijo y otro con los parametros para inicializar la fecha y ademas ¿se puede poner dos constructores en una clase? Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el poco código que hice...

```
<?php
class Fecha{
    public $dia;
    public $mes;
    public $año;

    function __construct($día,$mes,$año){
            $this->dia = $dia;
            $this->mes = $mes;
            $this->año = $año;
    }
```

}
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo razón para considerar que deben ser *2 constructores*, cuando de hecho tu clase solo debe tener uno que sirva para inicializar las propiedades.

De hecho si declaras mas de uno obtendrás un error como este:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Fecha::__construct() in .....

Dicho lo anterior lo único que necesitas es asignar un valor por *default* a dia, mes y año de esta manera:

```
class Fecha
{
    public $dia;
    public $mes;
    public $año;
    
    public function __construct($dia = 1, $mes = 2, $año = 3)
    {
        $this->dia = $dia;
        $this->mes = $mes;
        $this->año = $año;
    }
}
```

Así pues observemos lo que obtenemos como salida tanto si no le pasamos valores al método constructor como si lo hacemos:

```
print_r((new Fecha));

print_r((new Fecha(4, 5, 6)));
```

Salida:

```
Fecha Object
(
    [dia] => 1
    [mes] => 2
    [año] => 3
)
Fecha Object
(
    [dia] => 4
    [mes] => 5
    [año] => 6
)
```

Como observas si no pasas argumentos en la instancia entonces se usarán los que declaraste inicialmente y con ellos podrás seguir.

Incluso de acuerdo con lo anterior si ahora escribimos un método que nos retorne los valores concatenados para *simular* una fecha podemos observar su comportamiento tanto si pasamos argumentos o no en la instancia:

```
<?php

class Fecha
{
    public $dia;
    public $mes;
    public $año;
    
    public function __construct($dia = 1, $mes = 2, $año = 3)
    {
        $this->dia = $dia;
        $this->mes = $mes;
        $this->año = $año;
    }
    
    
    public function fechaGenerada()
    {
        return $this->dia."/".$this->mes."/".$this->año;
    }
}
```

Instancias:

```
print_r((new Fecha)->fechaGenerada());

print_r((new Fecha(4, 5, 6))->fechaGenerada());
```

Salidas obtenidas:

> 1/2/3 
>  4/5/6

Recomiendo leas [este recurso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php)